# how to displaying void method contents

Tags: java

I get 3 errors when I compile the  program, I tried few other ways but still didn't get anywhere. The program have to display the passed in contents of the LinkedList, then look for the the passed in String's index and print it out, then print out the contents of the LinkedList in reverse. The method to do all of these are void methods in LinkedList Class.
This is the LinkedList:

```
   public class LinkedList {

   private Node front;
   private int count;

   public LinkedList() {

     front = null;
     count = 0;

   }

   public void addToFront(String d) {

     Node n = new Node (d, front);
     front = n;
     count++;
   }

   public int size() {

      return count;
   }

   public boolean isEmpty() {

      return (count == 0);
   }

  public void clear() {

     front = null;
     count = 0;
  }

  public String getFrontData() {

     if (front == null)
         return "Empty List";

     else 
         return front.getData();
  }

  public Node getFront() {

      return front;
  }
  //EX_1
  public void set(int index, String d) {

     if (index < 0 || index > size())
        System.out.println("Cant add. Index Out of Bounds.");

     else if (index == 0)
        addToFront(d);

     else {

        Node curr = front;

        for (int i = 0; i < index-1; i++)
           curr = curr.getNext();

        Node n = new Node(d, curr.getNext());
        curr.setNext(n);
        count++;
     }
  }

  // EX_2
  public void listAll(String d) {

     Node curr = front;
     boolean found = false;
     int index = -1;

     while (curr != null && ! found) {

        index ++;

        if (curr.getData().equals(d))
           found = true;

        curr = curr.getNext();
     }

     if (!found)
        System.out.print("did not find Anything");

     else 
        System.out.print(index);        
   }
       // EX_3
       public void printReverse() {

          if (front == null)
             System.out.print("The List is Empty");

         else {

             for (int i = size()-1; i >= 0; i--)
                System.out.print(i + " --> ");       
         }
       }


       public void enumerate() {

          Node curr = front;

          while (curr!= null) {

             System.out.print(curr);
             curr = curr.getNext();
          }

              System.out.println();      
       }

    }// Class
```

This is the Main program:

```
    public class LinkedListDemo {

         public static void main(String[] args) {

         LinkedList str = new LinkedList();

         str.set(0,"M");                                    
         System.out.println("Strings in the Linked List: " + str.set());
         str.enumerate();

          str.addToFront("M");
          str.addToFront("T");
          str.addToFront("N");
          str.addToFront("T");
          str.addToFront("L");
          str.addToFront("H");

          str.listAll("T");

          System.out.println("Number of T's in the List: " + str.listAll());
          str.enumerate();

          str.addToFront("T");
          str.addToFront("N");
          str.addToFront("T");

          System.out.print("Components of the list in Reverse: " + str.printReverse());
          str.enumerate();



       }// Main

    }// Class
```

This is the Compiler Error:

```
      ----jGRASP exec: javac -g LinkedListDemo.java
     LinkedListDemo.java:8: set(int,java.lang.String) in LinkedList cannot be applied to ()
          System.out.println("Strings in the Linked List: " + str.set());
                                                         ^
     LinkedListDemo.java:20: listAll(java.lang.String) in LinkedList cannot be applied to ()
          System.out.println("Number of T's in the List: " + str.listAll());
                                                        ^
     LinkedListDemo.java:27: 'void' type not allowed here
          System.out.print("Components of the list in Order: " + str.printReverse());
                   ^
    3 errors

     ----jGRASP wedge: exit code for process is 1.
     ----jGRASP: operation complete.
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: *"I get 3 errors..."* What errors?

Comment: Can you post the output of the compiler?

Comment: I edited the post, with main program and the errors

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) In the future, please try to be more specific.  Always cut/paste the exact error message, and point to the related line of code, if possible.

2) Even when you get past the compile errors, `System.out.println(curr)` probably isn't what you want.

SUGGESTION:

3) Check out this link:

[Printing out a linked list using toString](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19283083/printing-out-a-linked-list-using-tostring)

'Hope that helps...

=========================================================

ADDENDUM:

ERROR #1:

```
 ----jGRASP exec: javac -g LinkedListDemo.java
 LinkedListDemo.java:8: set(int,java.lang.String) in LinkedList cannot be applied to ()
      System.out.println("Strings in the Linked List: " + str.set());
```

CAUSE:

You defined your own method, LinkedList.set(), like this: `public void set(int index, String d) {...}`.  So if you want to use it, you need to give it *two* arguments: an integer index, and a string variable.  You called it with *zero* arguments: `str.set()`.  You need to call it correctly ... or call something else instead.

ERROR #2:

```
 LinkedListDemo.java:20: listAll(java.lang.String) in LinkedList cannot be applied to ()
      System.out.println("Number of T's in the List: " + str.listAll());
```

CAUSE:

There are two problems here:

1) The `+` in your System.out.println() is expecting a *string*, you're giving it a function that returns "void".  If "listAll()" returned a "String", that part would work.

2) The second problem is that "LinkedList.listAll()" expects an argument: `String d`.  You're not passing any arguments.  This is the same issue as ERROR #` above.

ERROR #3:

```
 LinkedListDemo.java:27: 'void' type not allowed here
      System.out.print("Components of the list in Order: " + str.printRev
```

CAUSE:

Again, the `+` in your System.out.println() is expecting a *string*, you're giving it a function that returns "void".  One solution is to change "printRev()" to return a string.  A better solution might be to have "printRev()" call System.out.println() itself.

Again - 'hope that helps!

Comment: Please don't post links alone. You should post the relevant parts of that link content in order to make an appropriate answer (if it's possible).

Comment: This is not an answer.  It's a bit extensive to be a comment, but it should be a comment.

Comment: Thanks Alot @FoggyDay, it was a great help