# How to print object within a linked list?

Tags: java, object, linked-list

First, I would like to apologize if I do anything incorrectly, as this is my first post and I am very inexperienced with Java. I wanted to know how I can print this LinkedList that is called "addressBook" without something like this, "Friend@8410b1", pop up in its place. Also, how can I loop this if statement?

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

public class ABook
{
   public static void main (String args[])
   {
       LinkedList addressBook = new LinkedList();
       Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
       System.out.println("Would you like to add a friend? (Say Y or N)"); 
       String reply = input.nextLine();
       if(reply.equals("Y"))
       {
           System.out.println("What is the name of your friend?");
           String name = input.nextLine();
           System.out.println("What is the age of your friend?");
           int age = input.nextInt();
           Friend newFriend = new Friend(name,age);
           addressBook.add(newFriend);
           System.out.println("This is your Address Book so far: " + addressBook);
        }     
        else if(reply.equals("N")){
           System.out.println("Thank you for your time");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This post on stack overflow should help you

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19283083/printing-out-a-linked-list-using-tostring

Answer (score 0):

For the loop: simply replace the if-statement with this:

`while((reply = input.nextLine()).equals("Y"))`

For the printing:
Override `toString()` in `Friend` and print this way:

```
System.out.println("This is your address...");
addressBook.forEach(f -> System.out.println(f));
```

This prints the whole thing unordered. If you want it to be printed in the same order as in `addressBook`, use `forEachOrdered(lambda)` instead. Instead of overriding `toString()` you could aswell implement a method of this kind:

```
class Friend{
     public void print(){
          System.out.println("name: " + name + ...);
     }
}
```

and print this way:

```
System.out.println("Addressbook...");
addressBook.forEach(f -> Friend::print);
```