# String toString method

Tags: java, string

This is the class with the `toString` method

```
class Person {

    final String name;
    final String address;
    final String phoneNr;

    Person(String name, String address, String phoneNr) {
        this.name = name;
        this.address = address;
        this.phoneNr = phoneNr;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return String.format("%-10s, %-20s, %-10s", name, address, phoneNr);
    }

}
```

Now I need to write this method in a `PhoneBookList` class that I created earlier. How would i do this?

Comment: Edit the class `Person`. Add the posted method to `Person`.

Comment: Hey,this method is actually in the class Person already. I'll edit the post so that you can see the entire class

Comment: Then it sounds like you implemented the method. Edit your question, explain what you need help with. A complete example would be good.

Comment: Okay I dont know why but when I try to implement the entire class Person it just wont do it, it only takes the first line as code  and the rest as text.I dont know how I'm susposed to edit than

Comment: "this method is actually in the class Person already" so what is the problem? Are you facing any compilation errors, exceptions when you run your code, or does it generate unexpected results (in which case what results did you expect, why, and what did you get instead)?

Comment: Yes I'm getting compilation errors when I try to implement this method in the other class, and i was referring to the formatting problem here not the code itself

Comment: I know that, but this is the only way i could rewrite it onto the site, the actuall code has all of those and is compiling fine.Its the class where i need to "rewrite" it that is causing the problems

Comment: @cody1 Where do you want to print person's values after which methods in PhoneBookList?

Comment: No warning at all, and i want to print out the persons values in the main method.I created also a main method in which i call all of the phonebooklist methods.And there I need to be able to see the actuall people when i call the methods

Comment: Okay I can actually see the problems in preview I'll just post the code as it as and maybe you guys can fix it. EDIT okay when i try to post the question it says that there is a problem in formatting of my code

Comment: Okay I'll do that https://pastebin.com/CMMjL412

Comment: Edited (didn't see any problems while posting it.. strange...). I also remove my comments to reduce noise in comments.

Comment: Yea very weird, now to explain my problem. See this class containing the toString method.The instructions of the  assignment say that i need to write in the PhoneBookList class that I created (that also wont copy on the site crazy).And when I rewrite it in the code I get an compiling error. I'll post the phonebook list on pastebin and maybe you can magicly edit it in cuz I really dont know what is up today i posted like 4 times no problems https://pastebin.com/sWnxzhy6

Comment: Purpose of `toString` method in each class is to generate `String` representing data held in instance of that class. Your `toString` in `Person` class looks OK, but `toString` in `PhoneBookList` doesn't because that list doesn't have its own `name, address, phoneNr`, all it contains are Nodes for each Person instance. So toString method of a list should *build* string while looping over all Persons in its nodes and using those persons `toString` results.

Comment: Something like (this is pseudocode) `stringBuilder; while(need to iterate over more nodes){ stringBuilder.add(currentNode.person.toString()); move to next node} return stringBuilder.toString();`

Comment: Possibly related: [Printing out a linked list using toString](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19283083)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just override `toString()` this in Person class and in `Phonebooklist` when printing any person object will use `toString()` values

```
public class Person {

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return String.format("%-10s, %-20s, %-10s", name, address, phoneNr);
    }
}
```

```
public class Phonebooklist {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Person person = new Person("name", "address", "000-000-000"); // if you are using constuctor overloading 
        System.out.println(person);
    }
}
```

, And if you loop over all nodes in Phonebooklist and use Person's toString format you can do this like this:

```
  @Override
  public String toString() {
    StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
    Node current = head;

    while (current != null) {
      builder.append(current.person); // this will append person object and use it's toString with this format "%-10s, %-20s, %-10s", name, address, phoneNr
      if (current.next != null) builder.append("\n");
      current = current.next;
    }
    return builder.toString();
  }
```

Comment: So if im getting this. I need to write the method in the PhoneBooklist class and in the main method just print out normally?

Comment: yes write the `toString()` in `Person` class and  in PhoneBooklist main method just print out normally

Comment: Okay this works but,it wasn't really what I was trying to accomplish.See if you recall the methods you helped me write. I need to create an extra class (Main) for those methods and whenever i call those methods I need to get this format out on the screen.Hopefully I cleared it up

Comment: https://pastebin.com/sWnxzhy6 here is the class PhoneBookList, it just wont post here for some reason

Comment: Okay, I read the code, Do you have for example `MainClass` and `main()` method and want to call `toString()` in class `PhoneBookList`

Comment: But you can not put `toString()` in `PhoneBookList` there is no access to `name, address, phoneNr` its related to `Person` class

Comment: Well the goal is to implement the toString() in the PhoneBookList.Maybe this example that was given to us could help https://pastebin.com/p2E7Y1px

Comment: Ok, let me check

Comment: Got it's just loop over all nodes and concatenate using `StringBuilder`, Does this what you want to achieve?

Comment: How exactly do i loop over all noodes and concetante using String builder?